# I have JSON. Now I want to render it on a page. How do I do it.

Tags: jquery, json

I am using jQuery and Backbone. I'm new to js. I can get it to display in an alert, but I want to throw info into the body.

something like:

```
var jsonData = $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=key&country=US&q=digital+camera&alt=json");
$('body').append(jsonData);
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping in a `ready` function?

Comment: Strange but I also dont see CORS headers - http://i.imgur.com/SOFn4.png

Comment: Hi, @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin, it won't return valid headers, because I didn't include a valid API key in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.write(JSON.stringify($.get("https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=key&country=US&q=digital+camera&alt=json")));
});
```

Comment: That was a really good answer. someone gave it a minus, but it had the key thing I needed (JSON.stringify). It is a good start for me

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to spit out JSON to for debugging purposes, it's much better to use the built-in console to let it parse and prettify it for you:

`console.log(yourJSON);`